# Span NSTableVIew Header for multiple columns

Tags: cocoa, nstableview, nstablecolumn, nstableheaderview

How can I span a header of NSTableView for more than one columns, i.e. I want two/three columns under one header. Like shown in figure:

```
|.....Header......|
|..Col1..|..Col2..|
```

I tried using two synchronous scroll view one on the top of another. The top scrollview/tableview has no header. It has only one row and I marked the first row as group row using `- (BOOL)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView isGroupRow:(NSInteger)row` delegate, and populating the extra header information in it. In the bottom scroll view/table view there are all data columns along with header. But it has the following limitation:
When I resize/reorder the bottom table view columns, the upper table view does not resizes/reorders. So after resizing/reordering the bottom table view columns, both table views do not look synchronized.

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this? I'm trying to achieve the same thing.